# Sort 2D Array to one column in ascending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java-8

I made this code for sorting the 2D array. I have to check on "duplicates" and "one empty column", but don't know which method to use

example:

```
 1 2 3
 1 4
 3 2
 3 3 5
```

result:

```
 3 2 
 3 3 5 
 1 2 3 
 1 4
```

```
    public int[][] arrSort(int[][] arr) {
        Arrays.sort(arr, (obj1, obj2) -> {
                if (obj1.length == 0) { return 1; }       
                if (obj2.length == 0) { return -1; }        
                int min = Math.min(obj1.length, obj2.length); 
                for (int i = 0; i < min ; i++) {
                   if (obj1[i] != obj2[i]) {                 
                        return obj2[i] - obj1[i];             
                    }  
                }
               return 1;                                
            }); 
      return arr;}}
```

Comment: What is expected output? Can you please share one example?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the code for you, and I also added some comments for you to use and understand.

#### EDIT

I fixed the answer with better code and more edge cases.

```java
private static int[][] sort(int[][] arr) {
        Arrays.sort(arr, (obj1, obj2) -> {
            if(obj1.length == 0) return 1; // Make the first array go backwards if it has no items
            if(obj2.length == 0) return -1; // Make the second array go backwards if it has no items

            if(obj1.length > obj2.length) return -1;
            if(obj2.length > obj1.length) return 1;


            int score1 = 0, score2 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
                if(obj1[i] > obj2[i])
                    score1++;
                else if(obj2[i] > obj1[i])
                    score2++;
            }

            // Make the result negative
            return -Integer.compare(score1, score2);
        });
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. How to do this in java 8? Cause "case" was added in java 14 probably

Comment: it was added in java 8, also please don't use this as I messed up a tiny bit and the results are a bit off, I will edit it as soon as its fixed

Note: The -> was added in newer versions, instead of it use:

case:
code
break;

Comment: @DmitriyKrutenko I fixed the code, and now you should be able to use it.

Comment: checked this out, this code fails next test:
one, two, empty columns and duplicate

Comment: What should it do on duplicate?

Comment: check if it present in array or not

Comment: And then do what with said info?